# Problema con bindParam: "ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name"

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

Estoy intentando insertar un usuario y su contraseña en mi base de datos Oracle.
Cuando inserto un nombre y una contraseña básica, todo bien. Pero cuando intento insertar una usuario, con una contraseña hasheada, no me da error, pero tampoco me hace nada.

Adjunto el código:

```
<?php 
require_once "../INCLUDES/conn.php";

$con = connection();
$user = 'usuario';
$pass = password_hash('K899XMu8ee4I', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$statement = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (name, pass) VALUES (:user, 
:pass)");
$statement->bindParam(':user', $user);
$statement->bindParam(':pass', $pass);
$statement->execute();
$con = null;
?>
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> Array ( 
>     [0] => HY000
>     [1] => 1745
>     [2] => OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:159) 
> )
> ```

Comment: ¿la longitud de $pass entra en el campo de la base de datos?

Comment: @track3r Sí, le he puesto un tamaño de 1000 para asegurarme... jajajaja

Comment: O prueba a mostrar los posibles errores: $arr = $statement->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);

Comment: Error que muestra: Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1745 [2] => OCIStmtExecute: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:159) )

Comment: Posiblemente los datos que intentas insertar son duplicados. Revisar el error_log o imprime por pantalla los mensajes de error.

Comment: Ese error ocurre cuando en los nombres de parámetros usas palabras reservadas de Oracle u otras palabras no permitidas. Prueba cambiando la consulta así: `INSERT INTO usuarios (name, pass) VALUES (:myuser, 
:mypass)`  y en los bind: **`$statement->bindParam(':myuser', $user);
$statement->bindParam(':mypass', $pass);`**

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por la ayuda, escasos segundos antes encontré la solución.

Comment: De nada. En estos casos habría sido mejor dar la oportunidad a quienes han intentado ayudarte de responder, en lugar de escribir una auto-respuesta. Ello podría haber dado lugar a una respuesta más rica, indicando otras posibilidades de hacerlo, por ejemplo, usando marcadores de posición y pasando un array con los parámetros en el `execute`. En todo caso, me alegro de que te haya funcionado.  Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Al parecer `USER` es una [**palabra reservada**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) para Oracle.

La solución ha sido cambiar `:user` por `:usuario`.